# Need help in parsing data from XML through JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xml-parsing

I am trying to make a portable app in javascript that pulls out data from an XML file and display it in a datagrid. This data has some fields that will definitely have some data in them and some fields that may or may not contain data. The second field is of author and my data can contain from 1 to 9 authors. All of this data is in excel file from which i converted to xml and it obviously doesnt contain the tags like `<author2>`,  `<author3>`, et cetera, if they are not there for a record.

Firstly, while parsing the data through javascript, I had to keep this:

```
document.createTextNode(x[i].getElementsByTagName("author3")[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue);
```

...in try-catch block as I couldn't find any alternative. Simply checking the tag's existence with "if" doesnt work. I think this method is not very efficient.

Secondly, with the authors field, I want to add as many rows, withing each row in the table, as there are number of authors in the record. For this I tried adding `\n` in between the authors and creating a text node out of it, but it doesnt help.

Comment: 1) Showing us the relevant code always helps!  2) It is not clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

As was said before, it helps if you **post some of your code and a sample of the XML**.

Having said that, here are some hint that may (or may not) help you.

You say *"Simply checking the tag's existence with `if` doesnt work"*. I assume you meant doing something like this:

```
if (x[i].getElementsByTagName("author3")[0]) { /* [...] */ }
```

... gave you a `TypeError`.

The reason for this is quite simple. If  `<author3>` doesn't exist, `getElementsByTagName` will return an empty collection. Because of that, `x[i].getElementsByTagName("author3")[0]` will always be `undefined`.

You can fix this in a few ways. One of the ways is using `try`/`catch`, which is a perfectly valid solution. Another way is to check the length of the collection, like so:

```
var author3 = x[i].getElementsByTagName("author3");
var author3_name;
var author3_node;

if (author3.length > 0) {
    author3_name = author3[0].childNodes[0].nodeValue;
    author3_node = document.createTextNode(author3_name);
    // Do something with author3_node
}
```

Note that this will still throw a `TypeError` if, for example, the `<author3>` tag turns out not to have any children...

As for your second problem: in HTML, any unneeded whitespace is ignored. This includes newline characters (`\n`). To insert a line break in HTML, you'll have to add a `<br />`:

```
document.createElement('br');
```

Comment: Has this answered your question? If so, please mark it as accepted. If not, please amend your question so someone can give you a more accurate answer.